# Setting FontFamily in OpenLayers Text Label

Tags: openlayers, font

Changing the font-Family of a style objects' text label does not have an impact - it always looks the same, no matter what font-family I set. Do I have to provide the respective fonts to openlayers somehow or do I have to do something else?

```
            var fontFamily = "Arial"; // "Verdana" // "Courier New";
            style.setText(new ol.style.Text({
                text: 'my-label',
                font: '12px bold '+fontFamily,
                overflow: true,
            }));
```

---

Funnily, `fontFamily = "Helvetica, sans-serif";` works, while `fontFamily = "Helvetica";` and `fontFamily = "sans-serif";` do not work (i.e. is displayed with the default serify font). Any explanation for that?

Comment: It isn't only an OpenLayers issue you can see the same effect in the Mozilla examples (at least when using Chrome and Edge) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font

Comment: Very interesting, but what is the reason for this?

Comment: The examples are correct after all, it's your syntax "font-style, font-variant and font-weight must precede font-size"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax so you need 'bold 12px '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for the same reasons, I found this to be a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459826/how-to-get-a-label-bold-in-open-layers-3

Basically [Mike](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/102658/mike)'s solution in the comments on your question.

I've verified that this works for OpenLayers 6.5 as well. So apparently, the syntax is very sensitive. `Bold` must be lowercase (`bold`) and must be followed by the other two parameters, separated by one space. E.g.:

```
var fontFamily = "Arial, Verdana, Courier New";
style.setText(new ol.style.Text({
  text: 'my-label',
  font: 'bold 12px ' + fontFamily,
  overflow: true,
}));
```

This doesn't work, because it's missing the 2nd and 3rd parameters: `font: 'bold'`

And this breaks entirely if I don't have access to font family in the given context, e.g.: `font: 'bold 12px Open Sans'`. Not even the `bold` or `12px` will have any effect, because the inclusion of an invalid font breaks the whole line.

So a safe bet is something like this, which uses system fonts (unless you've correctly provided other fonts within the context): `font: 'bold 12px Arial, Verdana, Courier New'`

Or something more general like this works as well: `font: 'bold 12px sans-serif'`